# Signal Abort(SIGABRT) exception in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Recently I've been trying to learn how to create apps in my free time. I've been following Apple's Swift documentation along with their tutorials on creating apps. After I finished the "Connect the UI to Code" tutorial, I ran the simulator, only to receive a **SIGABRT exception in my "AppDelegate" Class**. I looked at the console and it says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FoodTracker.ViewController
>   nameTextField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fb572d0a040'

I even replaced my original file with Apple's file just to see if there were any differences (there weren't, with the exception of a few extra comments). Here's my ViewController class file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self

}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
}  

}
```

Comment: check your`nameTextField` connection in storyBoard?

Comment: The trailing semi colon makes we wonder if you set up an IBAction instead of an IBOutlet from your Storyboard. As Joe mentioned, check your Storyboard and see if you have an exclamation point on your connections.

Comment: i don't see any exclamation points.

Comment: Upload your project some place so that I can download and try it out.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0lXmLqP87aON0wwckJucWhSbms Uploaded it to Google Drive. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you have inconsistent Storyboard to code bindings. The screenshot below shows you the exclamation points where Xcode complains. Delete and re-add them.

[image]

Comment: If this helped, mark it as an answer so that it's useful for others.